# Hibernate: optional many-to-one with not-null columns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hbm

I've got an optional many-to-one relationship between two classes. Hibernate translates the property to be optional by setting the foreign keys to null.

My db-schema does not allow the columns to be null. The property to be optional is represented by the default-value of these columns.

```
<class name="sth.Alpha" ...>
    ....
    <many-to-one name="beta" not-found="ignore" class="sth.Beta" insert="true" update="true">
        <column name="a1/>
        <column name="a2/>
    </many-to-one>
</class>

<class name="sth.Alpha" ...>
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="b1" type="int">
            <column name="b1" precision="8" scale="0"/>
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="b2" type="int">
            <column name="b2" precision="8" scale="0"/>
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

selecting data is no problem because of `not-found="ignore"` in the may-to-one-tag it will result in a `null`-`beta`-object. But if I want to insert an `Alpha`?  with `beta` set to `null`. I get an Exception, that it is not possible to insert `null` to `a1` and `a2`.

I get rid of that problem if I set `insert` and `update` to false. But this results in not saving the relationship if it is set.

Database-Schema cannot be changed and Hibernate-version is fixed to 3.5

I would also be happy if you tell me, that it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[how to use 0 instead of null](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.aspx) in conjunction with `<id unsavedvalue="whatever">` might help

or

[other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774581/671619)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, sound promising. But the page you are linking is for at least a few day down. But I will try the unsavedvalue-property